# How to check SSD disk space in laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, ssd

I have 8GB of SSD in my Lenovo Ideapad z510 laptop. How do I check how many GB SSD is installed in my system.
Is this 8GB of Soled State Drive is being used for boot purpose?
If yes, how much time it should take to boot my system. I have intel i5 processor with Win8.1 OS and 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Your PC has what is called a SSHD, or a hybrid drive, which is an old-fashioned *spinning* hard drive with a 8GB SSD built-in for performance purposes. As the SSD is managed by firmware, there is no easy way for you to check what files (and their size) are being cached on the SSD.

The SSD-part of the drive will be used for boot purposes as well as caching of some often used system files. But there is no way for you to control this process. At least not one that is supposed to be controlled by the user.

Juts rest assured that the SSD component is helping the performance of your PC. If you're interested, you can learn more by reading [this article](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/solutions/solid-state-hybrid/) from Seagate, which is the company which produced the SSHD in your laptop system.

Comment: Thanks.
One more thing. What about the laptops which only has SSD/SSHD installed in it? How do they know about their SSD/SSHD size. Also, As I know, SSDs are very fast but at the same time its a flash drive type memory so it must work as a pendrive. I mean it would have some count and post that it will degrade in its performance.

Comment: A SSD drive should not degrade in performance. But if it's *heavily* used, you could eventually end up with a broken drive. This, however, would require very intensive use for several years. There's some further reading on this available [here](http://techreport.com/review/24841/introducing-the-ssd-endurance-experiment).

Comment: Well, As my system uses SSHD for boot. What do you think...how much time it should take to boot up?
I don't know why my system takes more time to boot than a normal laptop takes. Though my laptop is new and has 4GB of RAM with i5 intel processor.
It became slow after 2-3 months when I actually bought it.